# Simple Probability Question and Confusion

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I was reading an MIT Problem Set and one of the first questions was confusing. It asked. If you flip a coin 3 times, determine the probability of events. Assume all sequences are equally likely.
So I assigned 1/2 probability to each flip. And I know that you multiply each one to get the probability for getting all H or T.

P(3 heads)

The confusing part is that the solution says that there are 8 elements. How is that calculated? I get that it is 2 to the power of 3 but I'm not understanding why it is 8 elements.

Comment: Ah. Ok. I did get 8 with that method. Are there other methods to get the same result? What if you can't list it out like this?

Comment: Hint: Each toss can result in 2 choices H or T.  So, there are $8 = 2\times 2\times 2 = 2^3$ outcomes, not $2+2+2=6$. Spend some time figuring out why it is $8$ outcomes and not $6$. Which ones are you missing in getting to only $6$ outcomes? Remember that an outcome must be of the form $ABC$ where $A, B, C$ are replaced by either $H$ or $T$ (two choices made three times).

Comment: @DilipSarwate Why does it have to be in the form of ABC? Is A, B, C referring to sets? So is it choices to the power of how many sets?

Comment: All right, let’s do it even more simply. The possible outcomes of three tosses can be written using three letters, each of which must be either a H or a T. So, for example, HTT represents the outcome where the first toss resulted in Heads and the next two in Tails. Can you figure out why there must be 8 possible outcome? Horrors, can you generalize to the case of $n$ tosses?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Because each new toss (n) will create more combinations of possibilities. So, if we tossed it 5 times, it is 2 to the power of 5...32 possible outcomes. 5 tosses would create combinations like HHHHH, HHHHT, HHHTT, HHTTT, etc